# XML parsing: line 64, character 74, unexpected end of input

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying this query

```
SELECT
        [Code],
        tbl.Id AS PnlId,
        CAST('<t>' + REPLACE(tbl.Line,
        '|',
        '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS xml) x      
    FROM
        [dbo].[Temp] AS tbl
```

As example :

```
Id   Line
1    102|103|104 // suppose line is too long
```

I always got

> XML parsing: line 64, character 74, unexpected end of input

Any idea how to resolve it ? Many thanks in advance .

Comment: How about some sample data? I have lots of ideas how to resolve it but they all depend on what you data looks like.

Comment: Pretty sure you have oversimplified for posting. The sample data and the code you posted work fine together. declare @ table table(ID int, Line varchar(20))

insert @ table 
select 1, '102|103|104'

select ID, CAST('<t>' + REPLACE(Line, '|', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS xml) x 
from @ table